Does a company's constitution bind if there are any matters of shareholding?
Hypothetically, in a regulation of a company's constitution, it is written that A will be employed as a worker with additional shares given (he already owns some shares) which will be forfeited if he is terminated. Is this a valid regulation or is it not since A is not a member here?

The question is unclear.

What do you mean "A is not a member here"? By definition, "member" in the context of a limited company limited by shares means a shareholder.
